# Shell Script Automation

Tags: shell, expect

How to use `expect` and `send` in shell script.

How to input the answer automatically. I tried to login su with script that input password automatically. This is what i have tried but not work :

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect
su
expect "Password:"
send -- "test"
```

the error message is :

```
couldn't read file "Password:": no such file or directory
./auto.sh: line 5: send: command not found
```

Comment: I removed the various greetings from your question as we are indeed here to help you. Anyway, the question is still not quite clear. Could you please try to rephrase it?

Comment: what should i add here ? hehe, the goal maybe ?

Comment: Two shebang lines at the top don't work. You either use the one for expect or the one for bash... Maybe you should [read the expect examples first](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to log as *theuser* using the password *thepassword*, the following [`expect`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/) script will do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn su theuser
expect "Password: "
send -- "thepassword\r"
interact
```

Among the various pitfalls: of course, you have to provide a correct shebang. And do not forget the end-of-line character (`\r`) as it is not implied.

To quote `man expect`:

> **send** [-flags] string
>
> Sends string to the current process.  For example, the command
>
> ```
>              send "hello world\r"
> ```
>
> sends the characters, h e l l o  w o r l d  to the
>     current process.  (Tcl includes  a  printf-like  command  (called
>     format) which can build arbitrarily complex strings.)
>
> Characters  are  sent  immediately  although  programs with line-
>     buffered input will not read the characters until a return  char-
>     acter is sent.  **A return character is denoted "\r"**.

---

That being said, I can't refrain myself to warn you about providing a password as clear text in a script file ;) Depending your real needs, there are probably some other options...

Comment: thanks for the answer, that help me a lot. i want to know what the different between \r and \n ? hehe of course i will not provide the password. I just want to know how to use expect. and this is the easy example for me hehe :).

Comment: @AdityoSetyonugroho I don't really now _why_ `expect` use `\r` instead of `\n` -- but it is clearly stated in the manual page... I quoted the relevant part in the answer.